# Cell wrap using vb.net & EPPlus

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, epplus

I am trying to wrap a value in a cell using EPPlus and VB.net / ASP.Net
Have anyone been able to do this? I searched SO & google, but no luck.

Comment: http://epplus.codeplex.com/discussions/258416

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This will wrap the value of a cell (EPPlus 3.0.0.2) c# code:

```
workSheet.Cells[1, 1].Style.WrapText = true;
```